# IOS Push Notifications: Not getting any push when sending this payload

Tags: php, iphone, ios

When i am trying to send the following payload for generating a push notification on iphone, i receive a successful message but i do not receive any push notifications.

I want to know if this payload in valid format?

```
{
    "aps": {
        "alert": "green commented on your post: 'push post for tim'. Comment is: hey hi!",
        "sound": "default"
    },
    "type": "comment",
    "post": {
        "post_id": "168",
        "post_title": "push post for tim",
        "post_content": "testing push",
        "post_status": "1",
        "is_favorite": "0",
        "post_comment_count": "9",
        "username": "test1",
        "category": "uncategorized",
        "relevancy": "0%",
        "creator_num": "85",
        "type": "Manual",
        "lat": "0.000000",
        "lon": "0.000000",
        "auto_end_date": "0000-00-00",
        "access": "Private",
        "post_image": "http://thepost.com/admin/uploads/thumb/post_default.jpg",
        "post_comments": "9"
    }
}
```

The push is working when i am only sending this payload:

```
{
    "aps": {
        "alert": "green commented on your post: 'push post for tim'. Comment is: hey hi!",
        "sound": "default"
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum size for a notification payload is 256 bytes. APNS will refuse any notification that exceeds the limit. Your payload is 567 bytes which is why it's you're not seeing the notification go through.

Source: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html